# Java how to rewrite an MP4 video and change its orientation

Tags: java, android, video, header, mp4

So I have an mp4 video with the orientation set to landscape, what I would like to do is rewrite the file in portrait mode, I assume I have to change its header information or something like this so that it is rotated in a portrait format, does anyone know of a way to do this in java?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library, it does everything you need:

[isobox mp4parser.](http://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/)

Here is a code example on how to change properties:

```
IsoBufferWrapper isoBufferWrapper = new IsoBufferWrapper(new File(args[0]));
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.setProperty("ilst-\u00A9alb", "com.coremedia.iso.boxes.apple.AppleAlbumBox()");
```

Comment: Im not seeing any source code examples there unfortunately, are there any examples you know of that can do this?

Comment: I wasnt able to get this to work, are there any other methods that can achieve this in java?